# Calling member function as thread function using boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I tried calling member function as thread function using the following statement

```
boost::thread getURInHashThread(boost::bind(&Worker::run, this));
```

where

```
Worker
```

is the class and

```
run()
```

is the method. I have this statement in another member function of same `Worker` class so I gave that `this`.

But, I am getting the error

```
error:bind is not a member of boost.
```

I am not able to figure that out. Please help.
Thanks in advance :).

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
 public:
  void Main() { boost::thread t(&Test::run, this); }
  void run() { while(1){  std::cout << "some functionality here"; } }
};

int main()
{
   Test test;
   test.Main();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your preprocessor can actually find the boost include files? Are you sure you're not getting errors like "unable to find include file" or something?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan no i am not getting error of that sort. Actually I m doing some boost `mutex` locking stuff thats working fine.

Comment: Moving the `t.join();` at the end of `Test::Main` the above sample compiles and runs, as expected. gcc 4.6, boost 1.46.

Comment: Remove `t.join`, because there's no variable named `t`, and if you mean `test`, it doesn't have `join` function. Other than that -- your example compiles. If you want to use `bind` explicitly, include the appropriate header file.

Answer (score 0):

boost threads use bind internally so:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
  void Main() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test test;
  boost::thread t(&Test::Main, test);
  t.join();
}
```

Comment: even i tried that way as well, but its giving error like `error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::thread::thread(void (plxCollectorRedis::plxRedis::*)(), plxCollectorRedis::plxRedis* const)`

Comment: You're going to need to put up a bigger sample of your code. Because the above example works fine.